# A loop that keeps incrementing until the variable is smaller that the length of the child nodes keeps crashing my page. Why?

Tags: javascript

I have this very simple loop that keeps crushing my page.

```js
var listtest = document.getElementById("newlist");

for(var t = 0; t < listtest.childNodes.length; t++) { 
  var crash = document.createElement("a");
  var crashtext = document.createTextNode("some random text"+t);
  crash.appendChild(crashtext);
  listtest.insertBefore(crash, listtest.childNodes[t]);
}
```

```html
<ul id="newlist">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

Every time I run this loop, my page crashes. I can't even open the console. I know the issue has to be with the condition `t < childNodes.length`, because when I remove it, it doesn't crash, but I can't figure out what exactly is the problem with my condition, or code in general?

Comment: Every round of your loop adds an element to `listtest.childNodes`. You've created yourself an infinite loop because `t < listtest.childNodes.length` will always be true.

Comment: you have used childNodes here i think that can also count the childnodes inside the `LI` node.

Comment: @Andreas Hi, can I ask you something? I keep not understanding something about the order of each new element, and how does it effect all the others. Here's a https://jsfiddle.net/ch2qys4z/2/   .. I don't understand why is the 3rd element not next to element 1?  In the first iteration, `insertBefore childNode[1]` places the first element before `first`, but does it not now create a new line, and therefore the 3rd iteration should take into account this new line, and therefore put the 2nd element next to the 1st one just like it does for element 5 and 7. Please help me out.

Comment: That's the result of your script that generates invalid markup by adding the `<a>` elements _before_ the `<li>` elements (which is the reason for the infinite loop). 1. `insertBefore()`: `<a><li><li><li>`, `listtest.childNodes.length === 4`, 2. `insertBefore()`: `<a><li><a><li><li>`, `listtest.childNodes.length === 5`, 3. `insertBefore()`: `<a><li><a><a><li><li>`, `listtest.childNodes.length === 6`

Comment: @Andreas I think you misunderstood my question. My question was why does `childnode[1]` which places the element before the first `li` not create a new line like the rest of the childnodes do, except the last one. The only conclusion is that, the first and the last lines do not create a new line, for whatever reason. When you add the new element before `childnode[5]`, a new line is created before that `li`, and then the new element before `childnode[7]` appears next to the previous one on the same newly created line. But the same thing doesn't happen if its before the first and last line.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that your script creates invalid markup... `<li>` node consume the complete width of their parent. `<a>` nodes don't do this. All this is also visible in the DOM.

Comment: @Andreas I am sorry but how is my code invalid? Did you check the jsfiddle? It works as expected, my only question was, why when you place the new `a` element before the first `li`, it does not create a new line, but when you place it before the second `li`, it does create a new line. So, new lines are created before the second and third , but not before the first, and after the last. Please look at the jsfiddle for clarity.

Comment: You really should re-read my comments, learn how to use the developer tools (and in this case the DOM inspector) and have a look at the HTML specification which elements are allowed as a direct child of `<ul>`s

Comment: I think you need to read my comment question as well. You seem to think I am still talking about my original question with the infinite loop. I am not. There is no infinite loop here. Please look at my jsfiddle, that is all you need to do. I am checking my tool inspector, and there is no error there. That said, I did forget that `ul` can only contain `li` elements, but then, why do all the `a` element get created and placed inside without a problem? You claim above that there is an infinite loop, there isn't. This is not my question or issue. Please read my comment question & look at jsfiddle.

Comment: I repeat, my question is, why when you place the new a element before the first li, it does not create a new line, but when you place it before the second li, it does create a new line. So, new lines are created before the second and third , but not before the first, and after the last. Nothing to do with infinite loops, and while `a` elements shouldn't be inside `ul`, they don't produce an error. I don't know why.

Comment: And I repeat one of my comments from above: _"`<li>` nodes consume the complete width of their parent. `<a>` nodes don't do this. All this is also visible in the DOM."_

Comment: @Andreas Obviously I know that, since `li` are block-elements, but that in no way answers my question. When you try to create and add a new `a` element before the second `li`, it gets positioned at the white space after the `li` element, but since it's block element, it gets pushed down and creates a new line, but the same thing does not happen with the first and last `li` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding new elements to the DOM, you increase the `listtest.childNodes.length` by one, therefore it will never get to the last one because there will always be new ones created, you should copy the length in a variable `loopCount` before doing the loop:

```js
var listtest = document.getElementById("newlist");
const loopCount = listtest.childNodes.length

for(var t = 0; t < loopCount; t++) { 
  var crash = document.createElement("a");
  var crashtext = document.createTextNode("some random text"+t);
  crash.appendChild(crashtext);
  listtest.insertBefore(crash, listtest.childNodes[t]);
}
```

```html
<ul id="newlist">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Aha. I see now. And can I ask you one more thing? Why is it that, when I target a child node that doesn't exist, the new elements is inserted after the last existing child node? Shouldn't JS produce an error that the targeted childNode does not exist? Like in my example, if you cancel the loop, and instead do `listtest.insertBefore(crash, listtest.childNodes[20])` this, the new element appears after the last childNode. Why is this not producing an error?

Comment: Im not fully sure what you mean by that, maybe try making a new question for this and add some extra detail and example there, also make sure to accept this as the accepted answer by clicking the check mark under the up/down voting buttons, that way people will know this is a working solution @Ihateselfmoderation

Comment: @Ihateselfmoderation Have a look at the documentation of [`.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore): _"`referenceNode`: The node before which `newNode` is inserted. **If this is `null`, then `newNode` is inserted at the end of `parentNode`'s child nodes**."_

Comment: @Ihateselfmoderation _"also make sure to accept this as the accepted answer by clicking the check mark"_ - You don't have to do anything like that. It would be nice to accept an answer _that actually is an answer to your question_ so a question is marked as completed. Asking for upvotes or _"please accept my answer"_ is not really welcome here...

Comment: @Luke_ If you introduce `const` for a new variable than you might want to also get rid of the other `var` instances as well and replace them with `const`/`let`

Comment: @Andreas i kept them because it was original code written by OP and id rather not change that code